# Free IntPtr to IntPtr

Tags: c#, intptr, unmanaged-memory

I have class called `Parent` :

```
Class Parent
{
    String Name;
    IntPtr Childs; // this pointer actual type is 'Array of Child' and it was storred as unmanned array
    int ChildsCount;// count of 'array of Child'
}
```

and Class Child :

```
Class Child
{
    String Name;
    IntPtr Photo; //Byte Array
}
```

All Data are unmanged.

Now in some place in the Main program I have an `IntPtr` that points to a `Parent`.

If I try to free this Parent using  `Marshal.FreeHGlobal` The real data of the Childs will not be freed.

The question:
How can digg into them and free them automatically without write a step by step freeing code?

Comment: Why are you using unmanaged data?

Comment: Wrapping issue.. I am calling C++ native library and passing some data in the two directions.

Comment: There is no Santa Claus.  The odds that Marshal.FreeHGlobal() actually properly destroys a C++ object are already low, it doesn't know beans about a C++ destructor.  Or that it will use the correct heap, albeit that the odds are good when the C++ code was compiled with VS2012 or higher.  But the elves demand that you destroy each individual object, just like a C++ program does it.  Exporting a function in your C++ code that does it properly is highly recommended.

Comment: "Exporting a function in your C++ code that does it properly is highly recommended"
Of course this function is destroying what was created in C++ and it is exist I was asking about destroying the unmanged memory that was created in C# and sent to C++